# Halacha to discourage a convert once every 6 months?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, conversion-to-judaism, shulchan-aruch, contemporary-halacha

A friend of mine told me that the halacha of discouraging a convert three times has a little nuance - the convert has to make the second and third attempt (to persuade the rabbi to let him convert) at least six months after he got rejected the last time.

So, his implication was that if a convert gets rejected he can't approach the rabbi again the next day, or next week but has to wait for at least half a year before he asks the rabbi again to let him convert.

**Does such halacha really exist? What's the source?**

**And if not, is there really any mandatory timeframe between each rejection i.e. how long does one have to wait before approaching the rabbi again?**

Comment: Check YD 268:2...

Comment: @Sam full name of the source, please?

Comment: Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 268:2

Comment: @sam I checked and nowhere did I find such halacha

Comment: That's exactly my point ,however every bais din is entitled to follow their own procedures

Comment: @Dan the way we carry out (Orthodox) conversion today is much longer, drawn out, and more complicated than the way the halacha is set out in the Gamarrah or in the Shulchan Aruch; most argue this is a precautionary measure against creating sinning Jews in a world where the vast majority of Jews are not Torah observant (BH not the case in Talmudic times or when the Shulchan Aruch was written)